# 1080 TV (LG) but need to watch under 720 - how I switch?

Tags: video

I have a 42 inc LG (42LG70). I have a kodi box and need to make the setting into 720; I believe the TV works on 1080. How do I make the TV to switch to 720?

My TV works but from time to time the screen goes back for a couple of seconds...I've been told it is due to the 1080/720 resolution issue.

Any tips please?Thanks.

Comment: Who or what led you to believe the black screen issue stems from the fact that you're playing 720p footage on a 1080p screen?

Answer (score 1):

If your tv says that it is 1080p, it should be able to display 1080p and anything below, including 720p.  If your kodi box outputs 720p, any TV rated at 1080 or higher should have no problem displaying it.

There isn't really a way to "switch" your TV to 720p mode, it should just display at whatever resolution it's fed by your kodi box.  I would guess that something else is causing the issue, such as a loose cable or a faulty kodi box or something.